# App Catalog Provisioning broken

Tags: sharepoint-online, app, provisioning

Trying to create an app catalog in SharePoint online by following this tut:

https://blog.codeasite.com/how-to-add-an-app-catalog-to-sharepoint-online-to-make-custom-apps-available/

Very straightforward process but when I click 'OK' button, it returns me to the 'Apps' page and doesn't create the site collection. Even after waiting for a couple hours, /sites/appcatalog is not created. There is no error thrown and I can repeat this process over and over.

What is happening with the provisioning process? There is no other app catalog in our tenant.

Comment: Did you check you have sufficient permissions? These kind of actions are often apparently available to the users even if they are not authorized to execute them.

Comment: yes, I'm global 0365 admin

Answer (score -1):

You should already have an App Catalog at: https://yourDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/apps

Comment: Negative.."404 FILE NOT FOUND" at that URL. Are you saying it's auto created like the Content Type Hub? I don't see /sites/apps in the Admin center either

Comment: In the [Microsoft tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-developer-tenant) it says you have to create the App Catalog.. Also have a problem in which once I click "app Catalog" it says "Sorry, something went wrong"..